# python pandas dataframe column addition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, dataset

when should I use a lambda function to add columns to a dataframe, and when should I not?

plus, can anybody check this for errors?

```
v_to_c['time'] = v_to_c.apply(lambda row:\
v_to_c.checkout_time - v_to_c.visit_time,axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi @balabiad9, does my reply answer your question? if so could you mark it as so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lambda` for readability, however simply doing this will be much faster:

```
v_to_c['time'] = v_to_c.checkout_time - v_to_c.visit_time
```

The correct way of using `lambda`:

```
v_to_c['time'] = v_to_c.apply(lambda row: row.checkout_time - row.visit_time, axis=1)
```

Timing it will show us how much faster `.loc[]` is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

n = 10000
m = 10
resulta = [5, 13, 8, 52, 2, 1]
resultb = [7, 18, 17, 2, 1, 5]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.array([resulta*n, resultb*n]).T, columns=['Result_A', 'Result_B'])

start_lam = time.time()
for i in range(m):
    df['time'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Result_A - x.Result_B, axis=1)
end_lam = time.time()

start_l = time.time()
for i in range(m):
    df['time'] = df.Result_A - df.Result_B
end_l = time.time()

print('lambda: ' + str(end_lam - start_lam))
print('l: ' + str(end_l - start_l))
```

Output:

```
lambda: 8.113799810409546
l: 0.008104085922241211
```

Comment: Why use `.loc[]` here, and not `v_to_c['time'] = v_to_c.checkout_time - v_to_c.visit_time`, which seems to take only about half the time (at least here, for a dataframe with 100,000 rows)?

Comment: Good observation. I used `.loc[]` when conditions need to be applied, but that is not the case here